# Cannot compile wxWidgets with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I'm trying to compile wxWidgets with CMake. I cannot get it to work. There's so many error messages that I'll just link a pastebin with the logs here: https://pastebin.com/wLk4aSvy

The first error reported is

```
CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link 'C:/dev/libraries/wxWidgets-3.1.5/compiling/wx-config': operation not permitted
```

Luckily in the pastebin you can also see the commands and directories I used. As for details:

```
CMake Version: 3.20.1
wxWidgets Version: 3.1.5 (development release)
build system: Ninja
compiler: Clang++ (from LLVM package)
OS: Windows 8
```

Note that I used the development release instead of the stable release because the stable didn't contain any CMakeLists.txt AFAIK.
Please help me get this working, thanks.

Comment: I believe for this error: ***CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link 'C:/dev/libraries/wxWidgets-3.1.5/compiling/wx-config': operation not permitted***  you need to enable developer mode in windows 10. Related: [https://www.ghacks.net/2016/12/04/windows-10-creators-update-symlinks-without-elevation/](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/12/04/windows-10-creators-update-symlinks-without-elevation/)

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to build wxWidgets itself with CMake thingy?

The library provides everything you need to build the library itself- all makefiles and solutions are there.

You can also use pre-built binaries - just need to make sure you get one for your compiler.

Let us know if you have issues compiling.

Since you are on Windows and using MSVC do the following:

```
Start MSVC.

Click "File -> Open...", then open the wx_vcN.sln from wxWidgets\build\msw folder (I don't know what MSVC version you are using but you can check the official documentation which N correspond to which MSVC version)

Go to "Build -> Batch Build...", click "Select ALL", then click "Build". Go drink some coffee.

In the MSVC, open wxWidgets\samples\minimal\minimal.dsw or minimal.sln. Select "Build -> Build Project", then execute the produced binary.

If you can see the window whose title says "Minimal wxWidgets" or something to that extent - you are done.
```

Comment: > Why do you want to build wxWidgets itself with CMake thingy?
because that's what I'm using for my project
> The library provides everything you need to build the library itself-all makefiles and solutions are there
yes, it also provides a CMakeLists.txt so that I can use cmake, and has an article about it https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_cmake.html
> You can also use pre-built binaries - just need to make sure you get one for your compiler.
There is no prebuilt binary available for clang++ afaik
> Let us know if you have issues compiling
I do, and that's what my post is about

Comment: @JakubGamer, what OS are you trying to build it on? Windows? *nix? OSX? I understand you have CMake thingy to beuild your project, but what you can do is to build wxWidgets and then use the built library inside CMake to build your code. Please understand that CMake is not a build tool - it is configuration tool. And wxWidgets is already have all configurations stuff available for the build.

Comment: I think people are downvoting your post because your questions are already answered in the initial post. I'm using Windows 8.
Also, CMake is a build tool.
How would I build it on Windows, because ``make`` is not available on Windows? I know you said to use ``Build All`` on MSVC but I don't understand where I'm supposed to find that.

Comment: @JakubGamer, `CMake` is not a build tool - it is configuration tool. You create a special file of where to find the files needed for the build and `CMake` will generate a Makefile. Nothing else. Then you get this Makefile and use it for the build - either by using nmake or by using MSVC.

Comment: @JakubGamer, also see the edit for the answer.